# How to track requests in Django with an ID integer?

Tags: python, django, post

I develop an Django application in which when the user makes a POST, it creates some .txt files in the server.
All txt files that are created in a request, have the same ID integer in their name in order to differentiate among the requests.
For example:

```
with the first POST --> 1_file.txt
with the second POST --> 2_file.txt
```

To succeed that every function in my server code (views.py or utils.py) that creates a txt file have a function_name.counter variable to keep track the times that each function runs (by the users' POSTs):

```
def getEmail(email):
    getEmail.counter += 1
    with open(BASE_DIR + str(getEmail.counter) + "_Email.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write('%s' % email)

getEmail.counter = 0
```

But this way is very error-prone and with the Apache's restart all .counter change to zero.

Is there a more efficient way to succeed that ?

Comment: Use a database to store this information. Create a Django model with a `FileField` (that will reference the file).

Comment: @dirkgroten thank you for your helpful answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store data persistently usually people use databases. You can create a model `RequestMeta` for example, with one IntegerField to store count. Also maybe add a TextField for your name or type (`email`) and get it on each request: `RequestMeta.objects.get_or_create(type='email')`.

Or you can use Django functionality and store files with it. Using model `RequestFile` and a `FileField` you can make your life much easier. Via `upload_to` you can also easily customize where to store files. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield).

Also you can store counter in a file nearby, but it would be much slower because of needed IO operations on each request and I wouldn't recommend doing so.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I will apply the first way (database oriented) because it seems the most straightforward.